# Loop data from the table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, loops, t-sql

I have a table like this:

[image]

To get it I used simple query like this:

```
SELECT 
    [ID], ID1, ID2, [Type]
FROM 
    [dbo].[Test_DB] 
WHERE 
    [ID1] = 29
```

For all the records, that has Type = 2 value I have  to run the same query  again, just with a different ID1 value.

```
SELECT 
    [ID], ID1, ID2, [Type]
FROM 
    [dbo].[Test_DB] 
WHERE 
    [ID1] = 34
```

[image]

Than again, ID2 values 24 and 38 has to be checked, and their data added to the output result, until there is no Type = 2 values in Type column.

In the end result I need, in this case ID1 = 34 to be changed to ID = 29  and its values added to the output result.

It would look something like this:

[image]

I have marked in red the new data. The one I got with second query.Please note, that this is not all the data, just the example of how output needs to look like.

How to make that this would be automatic? That all records with Type = 2 would be replaced with the records that have Type = 1 ? There are many lines in DB, so this has to be done for all of them.

Comment: Hi AZE, I am not sure what you want to achieve. Can you provide a sample dataset? And the desired outcome?

Comment: "*For all the records, that has Type = 2 value I have to run the same query again, just with a different ID1 value."* Huh? If you're using a different value for `ID1`, then you're, by definition, not getting the same rows back, so what does this mean? How can you do something for the rows (this is what I assume you mean by "records") but not returning those rows how can you be doing *something* with them?

Comment: I have updated the question, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

So I was  able to write the script, but it  goes only 3 levels down (there might  be a lot  more). And I believe there is a better solution to this:

```
Select 
       B1.[ID1]
      ,CASE
         WHEN B1.[Type] = 1 then B1.[ID2]
         WHEN B1.[Type] = 2 then B2.[ID2]
         else 0 
      END AS [ID2]
      ,CASE
         WHEN B1.[Type] = 1 then B1.[Netto]
         WHEN B1.[Type] = 2 then B2.[Netto]
         else 0 
      END AS [Netto]
      ,CASE
         WHEN B1.[Type] = 1 then B1.[Type]
         WHEN B1.[Type] = 2 then B2.[Type]
         else 0 
      END AS [Type]
from
(Select 
       A1.[ID1]
      ,CASE
         WHEN A1.[Type] = 1 then A1.[ID2]
         WHEN A1.[Type] = 2 then A2.[ID2]
         else 0 
      END AS [ID2]
      ,CASE
         WHEN A1.[Type] = 1 then A1.[Netto]
         WHEN A1.[Type] = 2 then A2.[Netto]
         else 0 
      END AS [Netto]
      ,CASE
         WHEN A1.[Type] = 1 then A1.[Type]
         WHEN A1.[Type] = 2 then A2.[Type]
         else 0 
      END AS [Type]
from
(SELECT [ID]
       ,[ID1]
       ,[ID2]
       ,[Netto]
       ,[Type]
  FROM [dbo].[Test_DB]) A1
  
  left join

  (SELECT [ID]
       ,[ID1]
       ,[ID2]
       ,[Netto]
       ,[Type]
  FROM [dbo].[Test_DB]) A2 on A1.[ID2] = A2.[ID1] and A1.[Type] = 2) B1

  left join

  (SELECT [ID]
       ,[ID1]
       ,[ID2]
       ,[Netto]
       ,[Type]
  FROM [dbo].[Test_DB]) B2 on B1.[ID2] = B2.[ID1] and B1.[Type] = 2
```